# Powershell Code for a birthday cake

Tags: powershell

My son is a computer science major, and his birthday is coming up. I want to create a code themed cake for him. I have studied PowerShell code and created what I think is something correct and fun. However, I'm unsure and was turned on to this site to get help with it. This is what I have ... JularJ is my son's display name for his video games.

```
$day=11/21/2017
$today=Get-Date
if (Today=$day)
{
    echo"Happy 18th Birthday [Jular]"}
else
{
    echo"Eat Cake Anyway"
}
```

Comment: That's pretty sweet, but I doubt this will meet the standards for a question on SO as it is pretty much "opinion-based." (Among other things.)

Comment: Change your question to: `"I am trying to write a script that echos a specific message on a certain day"` and you might get a better response as it will be a more valid and specific question. Though people will complain you don't say what the exact error is that you are getting

Comment: This seems overly complicated. As I understand it, the specification boils down to a PowerShell script that accurately reflects the recipient's desire for consuming birthday cake, in which case `function Get-CakeDesired() { $true }` would suffice. It would suffice for me, in any case.

Comment: This probably would've been better suited to [codereview.se]. (I'm not an expert in the scope of the sites, though, so feel free to correct me.) They require working code, but otherwise it seems to fit there better.

Comment: Agreed with code review.

Comment: @Scuba FYI, this question is currently being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359433/should-questions-have-a-backstory-in-them-or-should-it-be-edited-out).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'd be inclined to say the code sample here is too small and simple for [codereview.se], the asker probably doesn't want a formal review as much as a brief look (possibly) and that questions asking to review cake code would be fundamentally off topic there, since I'm not aware of any commonly accepted best practices relating to cake code. There also isn't an actual question here (does OP even want a code review?) and I don't think the code is working.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm sorry if this is terrible.

It could be much worse ;-)

Two things - make sure you prefix variable names with `$`, and that you use `-eq` for equality comparison:

```
if ($today -eq $day)
```

And then separate your commands from their arguments with white space:

```
echo "Happy birthday ..."
```

Finally, imposing a bit of indentation would make it look more professional:

```
$day = Get-Date 11/21/2017
$today = Get-Date
if ($today -eq $day) {
    echo "Happy 18th Birthday [Jular]"
}
else {
    echo "Eat Cake Anyways"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a cool idea for your son! Here is how I would write your code in PowerShell

```
$day = 11/21/2017

$today = Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy

if ($today -eq $day){
    Write-Host "Happy 18th Birthday [Jular]"
}else{
    Write-Host "Eat Cake Anyway"
}
```

The `-Format` parameter is important for the Get-Date function. Otherwise it will always say "Eat Cake Anyway".

Comment: What if Scuba doesn't really have a son and they just made up the "cool idea" so they would get answers to an otherwise off-topic question?

Comment: I'm glad to see people learning PowerShell, regardless of the reason or intent (unless it's potentially harmful, of course).

Comment: Does that mean all powershell questions should be whitelisted as on-topic just because you are glad people are interested in it? In case you don't get it, my point is that you shouldn't be able to get around a question being off-topic just be making it sound fun/interested. I am not saying it is bad you have helped, just is it right (by SO standards)

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. But unfortuntately, it is not necessarily my 'position' to determine whether a question is off-topic or not since I don't have those privileges. I enjoy helping others with what I can, and this was a relatively simple question that I could assist with. If this was a question that didn't provide code or was asking a question about PowerShell in general, I would hope I or someone could point them in the right direction.

Comment: @Scuba: You don't have anything to worry about.  You know now.  The request is obvious and innocent enough to not get worked up over.  But I hope you're question got answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: @CoryEtmund: I agree, I like to help and am glad to see you helping too. Not saying you are wrong, just debating really..

Answer (score -1):

Here's a fix to your current code so it runs:

```
$Birthday = [DateTime]'11/21/2017'
$Today = Get-Date

If ($Birthday.Date -eq $Today.Date)
{
    'Happy 18th Birthday, JularJ!'
}
Else
{
    'Eat Cake Anyways'
}
```

---

Here's a bonus, put this into a `.bat` or `.cmd` file and you don't need to worry about executionpolicy stuff:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -NoLogo -EncodedCommand "JABCAGkAcgB0AGgAZABhAHkAIAA9ACAAWwBEAGEAdABlAFQAaQBtAGUAXQAnADEAMQAvADIAMQAvADIAMAAxADcAJwAKACQAVABvAGQAYQB5ACAAPQAgAEcAZQB0AC0ARABhAHQAZQAKAAoASQBmACAAKAAkAEIAaQByAHQAaABkAGEAeQAuAEQAYQB0AGUAIAAtAGUAcQAgACQAVABvAGQAYQB5AC4ARABhAHQAZQApAAoAewAKACAAIAAgACAAJwBIAGEAcABwAHkAIAAxADgAdABoACAAQgBpAHIAdABoAGQAYQB5ACwAIABKAHUAbABhAHIASgAhACcACgB9AAoARQBsAHMAZQAKAHsACgAgACAAIAAgACcARQBhAHQAIABDAGEAawBlACAAQQBuAHkAdwBhAHkAcwAnAAoAfQA="
```

This is your script encoded in base64 and will execute all the same.

You can validate by running the following in PowerShell:

```
[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('JABCAGkAcgB0AGgAZABhAHkAIAA9ACAAWwBEAGEAdABlAFQAaQBtAGUAXQAnADEAMQAvADIAMQAvADIAMAAxADcAJwAKACQAVABvAGQAYQB5ACAAPQAgAEcAZQB0AC0ARABhAHQAZQAKAAoASQBmACAAKAAkAEIAaQByAHQAaABkAGEAeQAuAEQAYQB0AGUAIAAtAGUAcQAgACQAVABvAGQAYQB5AC4ARABhAHQAZQApAAoAewAKACAAIAAgACAAJwBIAGEAcABwAHkAIAAxADgAdABoACAAQgBpAHIAdABoAGQAYQB5ACwAIABKAHUAbABhAHIASgAhACcACgB9AAoARQBsAHMAZQAKAHsACgAgACAAIAAgACcARQBhAHQAIABDAGEAawBlACAAQQBuAHkAdwBhAHkAcwAnAAoAfQA='))
```

Comment: `"put this into a .bat or .cmd file"`... it's going on a birthday cake! I doubt execution permissions are going to be a problem

Comment: @musefan oh gotcha. well that's cool

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code. It works every year ;)

```
cls

$day=Get-Date -Day 21 -Month 11 -Year 2000
$today=Get-Date

if ($today.Day -eq $day.Day -and $today.Month -eq $day.Month)
{
    $age = (New-Object DateTime -ArgumentList ($today - $day).Ticks).Year

    1..$age | %{'.' * $_}
    "Happy {0}th Birthday [Jular] ! " -f $age
    $age..1 | %{'.' * $_}
}
else
{
    "Eat Cake Anyway"
}
```

Comment: What about on his 21th birthday? Sorry, I mean 21st birthday... though hopefully he will have eaten the cake by then I suppose...

Answer (score -1):

Here's mine, a shorter version without variables:

```
if ([datetime]::Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") -eq "11/21/2017") 
{
    "Happy 18th Birthday [Jular]"
}
else 
{
    "Eat Cake Anyway"
}
```

Happy Birthday :)